# JsonSchema: Validate an item in the List based on value of another attribute

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a requirement to put a check on value based on certain other attribute value in same object (both of them are inside list ) e.g paymentType is SHOPPING_CARDS, I want to mandate few attributes i.e paymentReference1 , paymentReference2 otherwise not. I have added this check , I am passing paymentType as CASH but still getting false error that required attributes are missing , though paymentId1 is being passed in all the items in list. Can someone please help to find out what I am doing wrong?

[Failing Impl](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/1An8ooOQ)

Error
$.paymentReference1: is missing but it is required

Update- As per one comment below , I have moved if/else in schema where this check is required but now issue is it is not raising any alarm when we remove paymentRef.

Json Schema

```
{
"type": "object",
"required": [
 "payment"
 ],
"properties": {
"payment": {
  "$id": "#root/payment",
  "title": "Payment",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "requestId",
    "requestTimestamp",
    "requestType",
    "orderNo",
    "orderDate",
    "enterpriseCode",
    "documentType",
    "entryType",
    "paymentRuleId",
    "membershipNo",
    "orderTotalAmount",
    "priceInfo",
    "paymentMethods",
    "createServiceId"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "requestId": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/requestId",
      "title": "Requestid",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "263e9575-09ea-45dc-b1d9-87ec7888d3ff"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "requestTimestamp": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/requestTimestamp",
      "title": "Requesttimestamp",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "2021-12-01T07:16:31Z"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "requestType": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/requestType",
      "title": "Requesttype",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "CREATE_ORDER/ADDITION"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "orderNo": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/orderNo",
      "title": "Orderno",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "9762909359"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "orderDate": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/orderDate",
      "title": "Orderdate",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "2022-05-09T14:01:21.000+0000"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "enterpriseCode": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/enterpriseCode",
      "title": "Enterprisecode",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "SAMS"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "documentType": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/documentType",
      "title": "Documenttype",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "0001"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "entryType": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/entryType",
      "title": "Entrytype",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "ONLINE"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "paymentRuleId": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/paymentRuleId",
      "title": "Paymentruleid",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "SAMS"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "membershipNo": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/membershipNo",
      "title": "Membershipno",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "10142100469959798"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "orderTotalAmount": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/orderTotalAmount",
      "title": "Ordertotalamount",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    },
    "priceInfo": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/priceInfo",
      "title": "Priceinfo",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "currency",
        "enterpriseCurrency"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "currency": {
          "$id": "#root/payment/priceInfo/currency",
          "title": "Currency",
          "type": "string",
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "USD"
          ],
          "pattern": "^.*$"
        },
        "enterpriseCurrency": {
          "$id": "#root/payment/priceInfo/enterpriseCurrency",
          "title": "Enterprisecurrency",
          "type": "string",
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "USD"
          ],
          "pattern": "^.*$"
        }
      }
    },
    "paymentMethods": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods",
      "title": "Paymentmethods",
      "type": "array",
      "default": [
        
      ],
      "items": {
        "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items",
        "title": "Items",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "sequenceNo",
          "customerPONo",
          "displaySvcNo",
          "maxChargeLimit",
          "paymentType",
          "svcNo",
          "unlimitedCharges",
          "paymentDetails"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "sequenceNo": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/sequenceNo",
            "title": "Sequenceno",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "1"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "customerPONo": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/customerPONo",
            "title": "Customerpono",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "0"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "displaySvcNo": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/displaySvcNo",
            "title": "Displaysvcno",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "719"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "maxChargeLimit": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/maxChargeLimit",
            "title": "Maxchargelimit",
            "type": "number",
            "examples": [
              159.27
            ],
            "default": 0.0
          },
          "paymentId1": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentReference1",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "T4543F/JCgkLnk6OT4qJ/hc+sg=="
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "paymentId2": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentReference2",
            "title": "Paymentreference2",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "ebdbbf2f-aec1-414a-a8b7-ec33de993c02"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "paymentId3": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentReference3",
            "title": "Paymentreference3",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "Regular"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "paymentType": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentType",
            "title": "Paymenttype",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "CASH"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "svcNo": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/svcNo",
            "title": "Svcno",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "6194995892193728"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "unlimitedCharges": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/unlimitedCharges",
            "title": "Unlimitedcharges",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "N"
            ],
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "paymentDetails": {
            "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails",
            "title": "Paymentdetails",
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "internalReturnCode",
              "authorizationID",
              "authCode",
              "internalReturnMessage",
              "processedAmount",
              "chargeType",
              "holdAgainstBook",
              "authTime",
              "requestAmount",
              "authReturnMessage",
              "authReturnCode",
              "requestId"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "internalReturnCode": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/internalReturnCode",
                "title": "Internalreturncode",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  ""
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "authorizationID": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/authorizationID",
                "title": "Authorizationid",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "940799"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "authCode": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/authCode",
                "title": "Authcode",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "000"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "internalReturnMessage": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/internalReturnMessage",
                "title": "Internalreturnmessage",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  ""
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "processedAmount": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/processedAmount",
                "title": "Processedamount",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "159.27"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "chargeType": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/chargeType",
                "title": "Chargetype",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "CHARGE"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "holdAgainstBook": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/holdAgainstBook",
                "title": "Holdagainstbook",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "Y"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "authTime": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/authTime",
                "title": "Authtime",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "2022-06-08T23:21:49"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "requestAmount": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/requestAmount",
                "title": "Requestamount",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "159.27"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "authReturnMessage": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/authReturnMessage",
                "title": "Authreturnmessage",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  ""
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "authReturnCode": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/authReturnCode",
                "title": "Authreturncode",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "000"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              },
              "requestId": {
                "$id": "#root/payment/paymentMethods/items/paymentDetails/requestId",
                "title": "Requestid",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "6bf404e0-d756-4247-9030-669c83d0d825"
                ],
                "pattern": "^.*$"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "paymentType": {
            "enum": [
              "CASH"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "paymentId1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "createServiceId": {
      "$id": "#root/payment/createServiceId",
      "title": "Createserviceid",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "PRE_FULFILLMENT"
      ],
      "pattern": "^.*$"
    }
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `if`/`then` is fine, it's just in the wrong place. You need to move it into the schema that has the properties you're working with.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "payment": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "paymentMethods": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "paymentId1": { "type": "string" },
              "paymentId2": { "type": "string" },
              "paymentType": { "type": "string" }
            },

            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "paymentType": { "enum": ["CASH"] }
              }
            },
            "then": { "required": ["paymentId1","paymentId2"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It solves my previous problem , but now opposoite of initial pblm is happening ..it is not raising error when paymentId is not passed

Comment: That just sounds like it's missing in the `required` keyword, but it looks like it's there in the schema you posted. (I assume you meant "paymentType" not "paymentId".)